# Why is useState hook has a previous value after form submission in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react frontend app with registration form. There is the useState hooks for values and errors and a function "handleInput", which handles input values.

Register.js:

```
import validation from "../api/registerValidator";
const react = require("react");

function Register(){
const [values, setValues] = react.useState({
        username:"",
        email:"",
        password:"",
        reppassword:""
    });
const [errors, setErrors] = react.useState({
       username:"",
       email:"",
       password:"",
       reppassword:""
    });

const handleInput = async (event)=>{
        await setValues(prev=>({...prev, [event.target.name]:[event.target.value]}));
    }  

const handleSubmit = async(event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        //form validation
        await setErrors(validation(values));

        //here is an issue
        console.log(errors);//*
        
        //clear form
        setValues({
            username:"",
            email:"",
            password:"",
            reppassword:""
        });  
return( 
        <div>
            <form action="/" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" className = "" placeholder="Enter your username"
                    name = "username" onChange={handleInput}
                    value={values.username||""}/>
                    <p>{errors.username}</p>//**
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" className = "" placeholder="Enter your email"
                    name = "email" onChange={handleInput}
                    value={values.email}/>
                    <p>{errors.email}</p>//**
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className = "" placeholder="Enter your password"
                    name = "password" onChange={handleInput}
                    value={values.password}/>
                    <p>{errors.password}</p>//**
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="reppassword">Repeat password</label>
                    <input type="password" className = "" placeholder="Repeat your password"
                    name = "reppassword" onChange={handleInput}
                    value={values.reppassword}/>
                    <p>{errors.reppassword}</p>//**
                </div>
                    
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" className = "">Sign up</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
    }
export default Register
```

api/registerValidator.js:

```
import validator from 'validator';
function validation(values){
    var errors = new Map();

    errors.set("username", (validator.isEmpty(values.username[0]||""))?"Enter username please":
    validator.isAlphanumeric(values.username[0])?"":"Username must contain only alphabetical symbols and numbers");

    errors.set("email", (validator.isEmpty(values.email[0]||""))?"Enter email please":
    validator.isEmail(values.email[0])?"":"Enter a valid email please");

    errors.set("password", validator.isEmpty(values.password[0]||"")?"Enter password please":
    validator.isAscii(values.password[0])?"":"Password must contain only ascii symbols");

    errors.set("reppassword", validator.isEmpty(values.reppassword[0]||"")?"Repeat password please":
    validator.equals(values.reppassword[0],values.password[0])?"":"Passwords does not match");

    return(Object.fromEntries(errors));
}

export default validation;
```

When I press Sign up button the //** appears, but //* is empty. When sign up button pressed again //* is defined, but it has a previous values.

[After first submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/notvQ.png)
[After second submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQeJy.png)

How to change previous value to current?

I tried to add async/await to my function, but it did not work.

Comment: Using `await setValues(…)` and `await setErrors(…)` will not help, neither of these functions return a promise.

Comment: `setErrors` doesn't change the `errors` constant in the current scope, the changes will only appear on the next render cycle. https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value